# What's the correct way to check if a collection exists?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

Previously I was checking if a collection exists by querying the namespaces.

Roughly like this, to check if "foo.bar" exists:

```
return 1 === $client->selectCollection('foo','system.namespaces');
                    ->count(['name'=>'bar']);
```

As this only works with `mmapv1` and I've moved to `wiredTiger`, I tried this instead relying on the driver throwing either "Database foo doesn't exist" or "Collection bar doesn't exist".

```
try {
  $command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(['listIndexes'=>'bar']);
  $server->executeReadCommand('foo',$command);
  return true;
}
catch( MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException $e ){
  return false;
}
```

I don't want to **list** collections as there are thousands, but I don't like relying on the exception as I notice the error message changed when migrating from 3.6 to 4.0.

What is the proper way to do this that's storage engine agnostic and future version proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listCollections` has a [`filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/) parameter that you can use to restrict the collections returned. It should end up looking something vaguely like `db.runCommand({"listCollections": 1, filter: {name: "foo" }});`

Comment: Thanks, looks promising and definitely ticks the future-proof box. Any idea if this uses an index internally?

Comment: I'm unsure. I played around with creating 10k collections and querying with `filter` and without. Without logging, and with using `filter`, it takes 0-1ms, and without it takes around 50ms. That suggests to me that under the hood it's using an index or another data structure that gives good enough performance.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I was getting around to it :)  Really appreciated.

Comment: After trying it myself, I concur. Filtering 17k collections as quickly as 2ms (iterating all collections took more like half a second, so filter seems performant) Also worth noting that my original namespace query is slower!